# BroadcastReceiver works on emulator not on device

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Parse to send notifications from device to device. I've set up a broadcast receiver to generate a custom notification when it receives intent from a notification coming in from Parse. The problem is that the broadcast receiver on the emulator works just fine but on the device it just does not receive the intent.

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="org.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="org.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="org.example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />


        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="org.example.app.Receiver"
        android:priority="999999999"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999999">
            <action android:name="org.example.app.A_CUSTOM_INTENT"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

An this is the onClick that calls for a Parse notification

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(context, "this is shown"     , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {

        ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"action\": \"org.example.app.A_CUSTOM_INTENT\"}");

        ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
        androidPush.setData(data);
        androidPush.setExpirationTimeInterval(120);
        androidPush.setQuery(query);
        androidPush.sendInBackground();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As I've said, this works on an emulator just fine and the device does receive notifications from the Parse service but does not respond to intent. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an error here :

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="org.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

I'm assuming the correct value is `org.example.app` (based on the rest of the manifest), so it should be :

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="org.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="org.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

The reason it works on the emulator and not on the device could be that the device has an older Android version. This error affects only 2.x Android devices.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! i can't believe i almost waisted 2 days on this

Comment: Thanks a lot I missed changing the first of those two entries as well.

Comment: what is diff between these two code . I dont understand .

Comment: @SAndroidD Wrong package name here : "com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE". Should start with `org`, not `com`.

Comment: but I m facing issue that notification works on emulator not on device.Plz help me